# Зачем нужен виртуальный деструктор при наследовании?

Tags: c++, ооп, деструктор

Насколько я понял, виртуальный деструктор нужен, чтобы в наследованном классе можно было вызвать (прямо оттуда) деструктор базового, а т.к. простой деструктор наследованный класс не понимает, то нужно создавать виртуальный.

И всё это, чтобы не было никакой утечки памяти.

Так ли я понял суть?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Не, немного не так. Деструктор базового класса из деструктора производного вызывать не надо (да и нельзя), он сам вызовется автоматически. Проблема в другом: деструктор *производного* класса может быть не вызван!

Представьте себе такую ситуацию:

```
class Person
{
    ~Person() { } // деструктор не виртуальный
};

class Spy : public Person
{
    Gadget* gadgets;
public:
    Spy() { gadgets = new Gadget[10]; }
    ~Spy() { delete[] gadgets; }
};

std::vector<Person*> citizens;
// наполнить значениями
for (Person* citizen : citizens)
    delete citizen;
```

Что случится, если в списке будет один `Spy`? А вот что: при уничтожении объекта типа `Spy` по указателю типа `Person*` вызовется невиртуальный деструктор `~Person`. Значит, память под массив `gadgets` не будет освобождена. Вот вам и утечка памяти.

На самом деле, кроме утечки памяти может произойти любая другая неприятность, ведь деструктор, на который вы рассчитывали, не вызовется! Например, может не закрыться файл, и при следующей попытке его открыть программа вылетит. Или не отпустится мьютекс, и при попытке его получить программа зависнет. Ну и ещё куча всяких катастроф может произойти.

Хуже того, по стандарту отсутствие виртуального деструктора в данном случае является undefined behaviour, то есть, программа имеет право сделать что угодно: отформатировать винчестер, признаться в любви к вашей химичке через «Вконтакте» или подлить валерьянки в миску с Вискасом.

---

Да, а в C деструкторов нету вовсе.

Answer (score 9):

Добавлю к очень хорошему объяснению пользователя [VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) следующий код, который очень часто можно встретить везде:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
  Base() { std::cout << "Base constructor\n" << std::endl; }
  virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Base destructor\n" << std::endl; }
};

class Derive : public Base
{
public:
  Derive() { std::cout << "Derive contructor\n" << std::endl; }
  virtual ~Derive() { std::cout << "Derive destructor\n" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Base * ptr = new Derive;
  delete ptr;
  return 0;
}
```

Результатом выполнения будет:

```
$ ./example
Base constructor

Derive contructor

Derive destructor

Base destructor
```

Обратите внимание на порядок вызовов конструкторов и деструкторов. Деструкторы вызываются в обратном порядке относительно вызовов конструкторов. А теперь уберите ключевое слово `virtual` из `~Base()` и `~Derive()`, как следствие деструктор класса `Derive` не будет вызван:

```
$ ./example
Base constructor

Derive contructor

Base destructor
```

Если от Вашего базового класса планируется далее наследоваться другие классный деструктор должен быть виртуальный. Рекомендую почитать Скота Мейерса, у него отличные книги по C++.

Comment: @mind_mixer

- Формально говоря, отсутствие вызова деструктора `Derive` не является следствием забытого `virtual`. Это **undefined behavior,** и компилятор вправе, например, просто уронить ваше приложение с segfault'ом.

- Если класс подразумевает наследование (или речь идет об интерфейсе), то [деструктор должен быть `public virtual` или `protected nonvirtual`.](http://goo.gl/dB4iaU) Вторая часть этого утверждения не менее важна, чем первая, поскольку позволяет вообще запретить удаление объектов через base class pointer.

Comment: - Я, кстати, вряд ли бы стал бы так акцентировать внимание на undefined behavior'e, если бы собственными глазами не видел, как в случае одновременной реализации интерфейса и наследования от абстрактного базового класса вызов деструктора с забытым `virtual` моментально приводит к coredump'у.

Comment: По поводу undefined behaviour и его сочетания с продвинутым оптимизатором: [[1]](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), [[2]](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html), [[3]](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html).