# Зачем нужен виртуальный деструктор?

Tags: c++, ооп, деструктор

Читаю одну книжку и столкнулся с таким кодом:

```
class Command
{
public:
  virtual ~Command() {}
  virtual void execute(GameActor& actor) = 0;
};
```

Объясните для чего нужен виртуальный деструктор? Если я его не напишу, то будут какие-то проблемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Виртуальный деструктор необходим, чтобы избежать возможной утечки ресурсов или другого неконтролируемого поведения объекта, в логику работы которого включен вызов деструктора.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{
   Base() { cout <<  "Base()" << endl; }
   ~Base(){ cout << "~Base()" << endl; }
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
   Derived() { cout <<  "Derived()" << endl; }
   ~Derived(){ cout << "~Derived()" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
   Base* obj = new Derived();
   delete obj;
}
```

Что вы могли ожидать на выходе:

```
Base()
Derived()
~Derived()
~Base()
```

Что может произойти (может, потому что, в общем случае, это [undefined behaviour](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)):

```
Base()
Derived()
~Base()
```

---

Для устранения данной проблемы необходимо деструктор класса родителя объявить виртуальным (`virtual ~Base()`), что позволит компилятору добраться до деструктора наследника по таблице виртуальных функций.

Comment: Не утечка, а UB произойдет.

Comment: @alexolut, что за UB?

Comment: @alexolut Просто по таблице виртуальных функций не будет вызван деструктор наследника. В чем здесь заключается неопределенное поведение?

Comment: @SergeyPestov Он про неопределенное поведение (`undefined behaviour`).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive: например http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/240150/240229#comment240237_240229

Comment: Окей, убедили :)