# Генерация виртуального деструктора при наследовании

Tags: c++, virtual, деструктор

Я знаю, для чего нужен виртуальный деструктор, но не совсем понимаю, что при этом происходит.

Если рассматривать виртуальные функции, то все очевидно: если наследник не переопределяет виртуальную функцию своего предка, то он (наследник) использует реализацию виртуальной функции, предоставляемую предком.

Как в аналогичной ситуации себя ведут деструкторы - я не понимаю. Ясно, что при вызове деструктора через указатель/ссылку вызывается тот деструктор, который закреплен за реальным типом объекта, используется позднее связывание.

Допустим, ситуация такая:

- класс-предок имеет виртуальный деструктор;
- класс-наследник не определяет своего деструктора.

Что происходит в этом случае?

Компилятор в любом случае генерирует деструктор, занося в таблицу виртуальных методов указатель на новый деструктор, а уже в этом новом деструкторе вызывается деструктор предка?

Или же компилятор не генерирует новый деструктор, занося в таблицу виртуальных методов указатель на деструктор базового класса?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Виртуальный деструктор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/240150/%d0%92%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80)

Comment: @Komdosh, мой вопрос не является дубликатом.

Comment: Ну там на самом деле есть ответ: "Хуже того, по стандарту отсутствие виртуального деструктора в данном случае является undefined behaviour, то есть, программа имеет право сделать что угодно", но ладно, отозвал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С точки зрения языка С++, если класс-наследник "не определяет деструктора" явно, то деструктор для него будет определен компилятором *неявно* (если это возможно). То есть для каждого класса генерируется свой отдельный индивидуальный деструктор. Далее все работает как обычно, т.е. если деструктор базового класса виртуален, то и деструктор наследника будет виртуальным.

В языке С++ нет понятия "таблицы виртуальных методов" и говорить о том, что и куда будет заносить компилятор можно только в привязке к конкретной реализации. Да, очевидно, что в тривиальных случаях конкретный компилятор может "переиспользовать" деструктор базового класса в роли деструктора класса-наследника в "таблице виртуальных методов". (Хотя в коде, сгенерированном GCC я вижу честную генерацию отдельного деструктора для каждого класса. Возможно это требование ABI.)

Как только в классе-наследнике появляются новые поля или новые базовые классы, требующие нетривиальной деструкции, или переопределенный `operator delete` (см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/590529/182825), реализации уже обычно не смогут переиспользовать деструктор базового класса, а будут честно генерировать новый деструктор для класса-наследника.

Answer (score 2):

С деструкторами всё ровно то же самое, что и с функциями. Если в производном классе должно быть какое-то особенное уничтожение - вам нужно переопределить `override` деструктор. Если с помощью `delete` производится удаление объекта через указатель/ссылку на базовый класс, то чтобы не словить неопределённое поведение, деструктор базового класса должен быть виртуальным.

Нет необходимости генерить какой-то новый деструктор, который будет в точности повторять поведение деструктора базового класса. Вызов всё равно осуществляется косвенно.